# Is there a robust way to set MAVEN_HOME in my ~/.zshrc without specifying the version number? (MacOS)

Tags: maven, environment-variables, zsh, zshrc

**Context**: I install maven with `brew install maven`

In my `~/.zshrc` I have:

```
# Maven (mvn --version)
export MAVEN_HOME="$HOME/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3"
export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**Is there a way to set my MAVEN_HOME in a way that allows me to not have to increment it when Maven is upgraded to 3.6.4?**

It is somewhat tedious to have to go into my config file and update it every time I update Maven! :)

This would also help an onboarding/setup script that could download maven and programmatically set up a `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` config

Comment: Isn't `/usr/local/bin/mvn` a symlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/mvn` (or whatever the last-installed version is)?

Comment: @chepner Ahh, I believe it may be -- I'll test this and see if it works out. This works out because I installed with `brew` right?

Comment: This works @chepner ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @chepner: `/usr/local/bin/mvn` is a symlink to the latest installed version when installed via homebrew.

I changed `export MAVEN_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/mvn"` to `export MAVEN_HOME="/usr/local/bin/mvn"` in my `~/.zshrc` config and everything is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done to solve this problem is to create a symbolic link that points to maven installation version.

`ln -s maven_3.6.4_path maven_slink`

And set the MAVEN_HOME=maven_slink in configuration file. And every time i need to change maven version all i have to do is drop maven_slink and create a new maven_slink that points to the maven installation. I don't need to go change configuration files every time I install a new version of maven.

Comment: Interesting solution, but still requires manual work after updating. For that reason, I don't think this is the answer I'm looking for. Thank you though.

Comment: You are welcome, : ) . This is what i used as quick solution in my case. It is better option that going to change all configuration when you have set the maven_home or java_home. It is true it need some manual work.

Answer (score -1):

I work on windows and i have created  folder dev-env and the path of this folder i have added in PATH variable.

I have installed the version of java jdk8, jdk9, jdk11, jdk13.
I have created bat files and place them in dev-env : jdk8.bat ,jdk9.bat, jdk9.bat, jdk11.bat and jdk13.bat.
Inside a bat files I do the switch of version of java.

```
@echo off 
set JAVA_HOME=path to jdk version
set PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin+PATH
java -version
```

Same thing in maven . I created different bat files maven3.bat, maven36.bat.

```
@echo off 
set MAVAEN_HOME=path to jdk version
set PATH = %MAVEN_HOME%\bin+PATH
mvn -version
```

So , If i want to switch from one version to another. I open the cmd and the run the bat file that has the version that i want.

Comment: This is great for when changing between known versions. However, not exactly what I was looking for because for every new version I would have to create the new bat file.